# TNSPing succeeds but ODBC connection fails

Tags: windows-7, oracle11g

I'm working to get Oracle 11g installed on a new system. We have an old PC with the same Oracle 11g install that works.

We have the .ora files on a network drive location. In the registry, we have TNS_ADMIN key pointing to this location. I have verified that the other registry keys are the same between the two systems.

Additionally, I know that there is no tns_admin.ora file anywhere else on the system. There is also no ORACLE_HOME or TNS_ADMIN environment variables set.

When I run a tnsping in command prompt, it instantly resolves and connects. It also shows the correct .ora files listed from the network drive.

However when I run the command prompt as admin, it fails with error **TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name.** The same error occurs when testing the connection in the ODBC driver from this Oracle home.

I've triple-checked (over 6 hours) the [search paths](http://www.dba-resources.com/oracle/tns-configuration-files-search-order/) and configuration. I simply cannot find out what the source of my issue might be. Does anyone have any ideas what could be the cause of this difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran across this again, and spent some 4 hours. Turns out there was a step in our install script (we run a modified install meant to run on our network) that wasn't working for certain machines.

This, in effect, made our network drive letter invisible to programs running as admin. Due to that, our TNS_ADMIN variable which pointed to "Z:\tns\" was not working. I was able to resolve this by ensuring the path can be found under programs ran as an Administrator.